# want multiple html data table in my asp.net form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am using one htmltable in my asp.net form but I want multiple htmltables at runtime like when I click on submit its selects releated data in my htmldatattable

I want to see particular id record in my particular htmltable which generated at run time how can i do this?

here is my htmltable code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

    HtmlTable dTable = new HtmlTable();
    dTable.CellPadding = 2;
    // dTable.CellSpacing = 0;
    dTable.Border = 1;
    dTable.BorderColor = "#cccccc";

    int tRows;
    int tCells;

    for (tRows = 0; tRows < 1; tRows++)
    {
        HtmlTableRow dTRow = new HtmlTableRow();
        HtmlTableRow dtrow = new HtmlTableRow();
        HtmlTableRow dtrow3 = new HtmlTableRow();
        HtmlTableRow dtrow4 = new HtmlTableRow();
        for (tCells = 0; tCells < 1; tCells++)
        {
            HtmlTableCell dTCell = new HtmlTableCell();
            HtmlTableCell dtcell1 = new HtmlTableCell();
            HtmlTableCell dtcell3 = new HtmlTableCell();
            HtmlTableCell dtcell4 = new HtmlTableCell();
            HtmlInputText txt = new HtmlInputText();
            HtmlInputText txt1 = new HtmlInputText();
            HtmlInputText txtAge = new HtmlInputText();
            HtmlInputText txtHeight = new HtmlInputText();
            dTCell.InnerText = "FirstName:: " + Convert.ToString(tRows);
            dtcell1.InnerText = "LastName::" + Convert.ToString(tRows);
            dtcell3.InnerText = "Age::" + Convert.ToInt32(tRows);
            dtcell4.InnerText = "Height::" + Convert.ToString(tRows);
            dTCell.Controls.Add(txt);
            dtcell1.Controls.Add(txt1);
            dtcell3.Controls.Add(txtAge);
            dtcell4.Controls.Add(txtHeight);
            dtrow.Controls.Add(dtcell1);
            dtrow3.Controls.Add(dtcell3);
            dtrow4.Controls.Add(dtcell4);
            dTRow.Controls.Add(dTCell);
        }
        dTable.Controls.Add(dTRow);
        dTable.Controls.Add(dtrow);
        dTable.Controls.Add(dtrow3);
        dTable.Controls.Add(dtrow4);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(dTable);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what exactly is your question. Can you please rephrase or elaborate more on your required output.

Comment: i want to generate multiple htmltable regarding my data selection

Comment: which is done at runtime

Comment: So you want to implement ajax communication and get the required data when the user click's on something?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your code into Init() method, not page_load.
Also [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484854/how-to-add-control-to-the-page-programatically-in-page-load) can help.